# Positions of relays in fuse box of Honda Accord 2003

Tags: honda, accord, relay, fuse-panel

I think that I swapped the position of these two relays.

Does anyone have any idea what the correct position for each of them is?

I can't figure it out using the diagram on the box.

[image]

Comment: Happy Holidays.  Can you take a photo perpendicular to the diagram?  It's a bit out of focus and the edge of the diagram is obscured by the side of the cover.  Have you tried swapping their location?  What systems in your car aren't working?  Cheers!

Comment: Also, what is your trim package and engine size and transmission type (LX, EX, etc)?

Comment: What is the real issue here? If you only swapped the two relays, there shouldn't be an issue because they are interchangeable.

Comment: Happy Holidays! Please see updated question, I've uploaded a better picture. Actually, I didn't noticed any issues, I just want to be sure that swapping (by accident) of relays won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**The relays are the same**

They should be interchangeable.

[Here is a parts diagram.](http://www.hondapartsnow.com/parts-list/2003-honda-accord-2dr_ex-ka-5at/control-unit-engine-room.html)

They control components of the fuel system.

Answer (score 4):

It is very likely that the two relays will be the same configuration, since their positions can be interchanged. But, there could be differences. One thing you can do to check is to read the part numbers on the relays. If they are the same, then the relays are the same and there is no problem with switching them.

The trick to reading the numbers is that there are likely to be two sets of numbers.

- The first will be the part number which will describe the configuration of the relay – the number of contacts, whether they are normally closed (on) or normally open (off), etc. If you do a search on this number or this number and the manufacturer (e.g., "mitsuba 7001" in your case, it should find relays like yours).
- The second set will be a manufacturing code of some sort, they are there to identify when and maybe where the relay was produced. This information is mostly useful to the maker for stock management or if they encounter problems. These number will probably not lead to anything that seems sensible in a search, but they may look like a date in some cases.

It can be hard to tell which number is which. In a case like your's I'd expect to see one set of numbers that matched (the part number) and a second set that did not (the manufacturing code). If both sets don't match then it is likely that you have relays that are functionally different – for example one might be normally closed and the other normally open.

You may also see numbers that have units attached to them, for example:

- 12 V - the coil (operating) voltage
- 30 A - the amount of current the contacts are rated to carry (possibly with AC or DC)
- 120 Ω - the resistance of the coil

Whether or not those numbers show up is less predictable, but when they do the ones that are there almost always have units (Amps, Volts, Ohms, etc.).